# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 in xcode 4.3.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode

![check the attached screen shot err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZDkl.png)[1].png][https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZDkl.png]
Hi,
I am a beginner in iOS development.We are trying to develop an application in xcode using objective c.We imported the libraries and codessuccessfully.And we were trying to configure the application to synchronize and fetch MBO data.When we builded our project we got an error.And I have uploaded the error with this post.Please check the attachment and help us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you did not add the MBOLogger framework to your project or linked it to the target.

Go to your targets info and check the Build Phases. There, under Linked Frameworks you should find your MBOLogger, or if it is not there, add it.

[image]

Comment: But I have added MBOLogger in my project root.Still it is showing the same error

Comment: please, go to the target info, as shown in the picture, and check under link binary with libraries that the framework implementing MBOLogger is there. If it is not a framework, but a single file (.h/.m), then check under compile sources that it is there.